# What does "with all the discrimination of a shotgun" mean?

Tags: idioms, american-english, comparisons

"If you scatter commas into a sentence with all the discrimination of a shotgun, you might make it to the foyer before we politely escort you from the building." Source: http://goo.gl/ZH6lO

Doesn't a shotgun fire one bullet per round? Wouldn't it be better to say 'machine gun' in this context?

-Edit-

Found this on the web: United States Code (18 USC 921) defines the shotgun as "a weapon designed or redesigned, made or remade, and intended to be fired from the shoulder, and designed or redesigned and made or remade to use the energy of the explosive in a fixed shotgun shell to fire through a smooth bore either a number of ball shot or a single projectile for each single pull of the trigger."

Comment: That’s not how a [shotgun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun) works.  It fires shot in a scattering pattern.

Comment: Did you look up in a dictionary what a shotgun does?

Comment: Sometimes a shotgun round is a [single rifled slug](http://www.sportsmansoutdoorsuperstore.com/guides/shotgun_ammunition_guide.htm). Most of the time, a cartridge with many little pellets is used. It's for maximum destruction at close range. A shotgun is often called a "[scattergun](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scatter%20gun)" because it scatters the pellets in a wide pattern, just like commas in 18th-century English.

Comment: You can see some info about shotgun shot patterns at http://www.firearmsid.com/A_distshotpatt.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [shotgun fires](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun) a large number of pellets (in one shot) in a very divergent scattered manner. Hence, the pattern of destruction is fairly wide. I would think the writer is trying to suggest (metaphorically) that you shouldn't overuse your commas.
On the other hand, a machine gun shoots a single bullet, linearly, at exactly what it's aimed at. This would suggest being precise when using commas (use a metaphorical machine gun for commas).
[image]

Comment: You need to use two returns to end a paragraph: `<br>` is not good enough, so please stop trying to use it.  ***It does not work.*** Just use two returns to create a blank line.

Comment: how about 2 tags?

Comment: You prefer typing eight ugly characters to using your return key? Why?

Comment: I was just confirming whether its me or the <br> tag acts differently here. But I see your point now. :)

Answer (score 1):

You've misunderstood the sentence because you have the wrong idea about what a shotgun is usually used for. This illustrates why a certain kind of background knowledge is always necessary to comprehend what you're reading.

Shotguns are usually used to fire buckshot pellets, but for special purposes, they're used to fire single bullets, either [rifled or non-rifled slugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun_slug).

The writer of the article you cite uses a metaphor for buckshot pellets, not a single-projectile slug.

The machine-gun analogy is OK, but that's not what the writer chose. Your question asks for a judgment, not an explanation. Judgments about the aptness of a metaphor aren't on topic here, because they're expressions of personal preference, not explanations of English grammar and usage.

Comment: Yup, you are right. I can only blame the movies for my misconception of how shotguns fire. :) The question did ask for an explanation of the metaphor used.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter how the shotgun fires (what kind or how many pellets or bullets).

> *With all the discrimination of a shotgun*

means *with **NO** discrimination*, since a shotgun will not discriminate. It will kill (hurt/hit/..whatever) everything in it's range.

In this context, *to scatter commas into a sentence with all the discrimination of a shotgun* means *to scatter commas with no regard for anything (with NO discrimination)*